# How to customize the icon of installer .exe created by install4j?

Tags: install4j

Whenever I create the installer executable file by running install4j scrip it always contains the default icon. How can I change the same to provide the company's icon? I am using windows platform.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the Installer->Screens & Actions step, select the installer and edit the "Executable icon" property.

Comment: Great!!!! ```How also we can change the icon of the produced.exe file``` ?

Comment: That's configurable on the "Icon" step of the launcher wizard